# Restore-SPSite : The Web application at http://site/ could not be found

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, 2016, restore, sql-server-2016

On my newly created SharePoint 2016 development server, I have one web application which currently stores our production server intranet backup.
Now I want to take the backup of this dev WA site and restore it on another web application on the same dev server.

I took the backup using PowerShell but when I start restoring the backup to other WA it gives an error

```
Restore-SPSite: The Web application at http://site/ could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system
administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.
```

I checked below pointers:

1. SharePoint admin account has dbowner permission in SQL.
2. SharePoint admin account is the part of WSS_ADMIN_WPG, IIS_IUSRS & WSS_WPG groups
3. The site on which I have to restore is accessible thru browsers.

Please provide the suggestions to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure that**

1. You are using the farm account and running the SharePoint Management Shell as Administrator.
2. You have added the `-DatabaseName` parameter to specify which content database will store the site collection in your cmdlet.
3. Use `-Force` when specifying a specific content database.
4. The specified content database is not `read-only` or `offline`.
5. The Max site collection number in the content database is not set to 1.
6. The specified managed path is created in the destination web app (if exist).
7. Only during restore, Add Web App Pool Account of the destination of web app to `WSS_ADMIN_WPG`, and `local admin`